# How I do know which modules are active or not in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm building a theme for my site with some particularities so I need to know if modules slideshow and module promotions are enabled or not, how do I know this? Can I check this from templates?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of how modules can have more than one on a store, and be in different regions of a template (layouts) this is quite difficult to do. You will have to query the layout and position much like the column left/right and content top/bottom do in order to see if the module is available in that particular region and on that specific page. For how to achieve this, see the code inside the controller of your particular install version `catalog/controller/common/column_left.php` for example

That said, most custom theme developers will create their own modules for the specific region you want them to be in so you can control this and check the status of the module using `$this->config->get`. This would be my choice of how to achieve this so you're not reliant on other modules for your theme

Comment: Hi @jay-gilford see this is what I'm trying to do: ![image](http://www.dropmocks.com/mBrw-n) in this case your suggestion is valid?

Comment: yes if you create your own specific modules, you don't need to rely on those integrated already and can have finer control over them